# How to select between 1st of this month to 17th of previous month

Tags: mysql, sql

I use this select query but after next month, data of previous month not to come.

```
SELECT xxx,xxx,xxx 
FROM lott_user_table 
WHERE MONTH(NOW()) AND DAYOFMONTH(datetime) BETWEEN 17 AND 1
```

How to fix or way to get data between 1st of this month to 17th of previous month (not use date_sub()) ?

Thank you (sorry for my english)

Comment: Your title and your question are inconsistent.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, I changed the topic.

Comment: Is there related PHP code or this is just a mysql question? You could construct the low range of the rate with `concat` and math and `interval` in the query. Roughly like `select * from table where column between concat(year(now()), '-', month(now() - interval -1 month), '-', day(now())) and concat(year(now()), '-', month(now()), '-01')`

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id,datetime
FROM lott_user_table 
where MONTH(datetime) between MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
                              and MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
and (DAYOFMONTH(datetime) > case when MONTH(datetime) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)  then 
                                     17
                            end
     or DAYOFMONTH(datetime) <= case when MONTH(datetime) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)  then 
                                     1
                                end)
```

Here is the demo:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3b00794c9a5d9af9fcb3dda19b6c5ff8)

Comment: Hi @RBP , did this help?

Answer (score 0):

`n between 17 and 1` will never return any row because it's equivalent to `n >= 17 and n <=1`, which is simply impossible.

You should try to make your condition *searchable*, i.e. avoid calculation on both sides of the comparison:

```
                       -- get the 17th of the previous month
                       -- = 1st of current month - 1 month + 16 days
where datetime between subdate(CURRENT_DATE, dayofmonth(current_date)-1) - interval 1 month + interval 16 day
                       -- 1st of current month
                   and subdate(CURRENT_DATE, dayofmonth(current_date)-1)
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=aea840cc91ad060407f326730b4c0759)